# Is it possible to restrict iOS app communication with only whitelisted domains?

Tags: ios, nsapptransportsecurity

I would like to *tighten* App Transport Security settings such that my app can only communicate with whitelisted domains, e.g. `https://bank.com/api`, and nothing more. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsapptransportsecurity/nsexceptiondomains ?

Comment: @matt Sure, if there was an option within `NSAppTransportSecurity` to whitelist only domains within `NSExceptionDomains`, but there does not appear to be such an option.

Comment: Do you not trust your own code?

Comment: @Paulw11 We do, but like the majority of apps these days, we use some 3rd party libraries for some things. We would like to ensure they do not send any data we don't expect them to send.

Comment: Then unfortunately there is no way that you can restrict your app's network connections. You will need to evaluate the convenience of using 3rd party code vs the potential risks. You can analyse the code if available and execute your app in a controlled environment where you can log and assess network activity.